# Reason why CSS file not reflecting on PDF using Weazprint

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to add style to my PDF file using a CSS file which for some reason is not linking to it. I have tried the following:

PDF template

```
{% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/pdf.css" %}' media="all" />
```

I have tried to link it through the views page:
views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
--------------------------------------------
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    return response
```

I am using the followig config in the settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
```